# Confusion regarding file structure of PHP/ HTML project (with a form)

Tags: php, html, path, filepath

Below is the file structure of my website on the domain server (not localhost):

```
public_html
--- index.html
real-estate-website
--- resources
--- --- sign_up.php
```

I have a form in my index.html file that points to...

```
../real-estate-website/resources/sign_up.php
```

I have tried adding a ./ before this, but it made no difference. When I submit the form from my domain, I get a 404 error, with the following url in the address bar:

```
[domain-name]/real-estate-website/resources/sign_up.php
```

Is there an issue with where the form is pointing or am I overlooking something else? Any help is appreciated. Let me know if I should clarify any part of my question

Comment: Is `public_html` the webroot? If so the folder your trying to access is outside it. Plop the `real-estate-website` folder into `public_html`

Comment: I am pretty sure it is the webroot. How would I get around this issue then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in a web hosting provider server, public_html is the folder where you put all your files that should be accessible to the users of your website (through a web browser), any file outside of this folder is not accessible directly from a web browser, unless you use some PHP code to deliver it in some way.

Here you are using an HTML form and using its `action` attribute which should always point to an accessible file, i.e. a file inside public_html.

My suggestion is to move the folder real-estate-website with its content inside the public_html folder.

```
public_html
--- index.html
--- real-estate-website
--- --- resources
--- --- --- sign_up.php
```

And change the `action` attribute value of the form to point to your desired file: `/real-estate-website/resources/sign_up.php`.

**UPDATE**

Regarding the comments below what I meant with PHP `include` is for example to create a PHP file outside public_html :

```
public_html
--- index.html
--- real-estate-website
--- --- resources
--- --- --- sign_up.php
config
--- settings.php
```

In settings.php you put the sensitive data:

```
<?php
const EMAIL_PWD = 'secret';
```

And in your sign_up.php include settings.php in the top of your code like this:

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . '/../config/settings.php';
```

So inside your sign_up.php code you should have access to the string constant EMAIL_PWD and use it accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure my files are secure even if I move them inside the public_html folder? I am asking this because some of my other php files contain passwords and validation to other parts of my website.

Comment: Hi, for security reasons, things like passwords and other sensitive data should effectively be outside of the web root (public_html) folder, and use PHP e.g. `include` to include files defining them, or `parse_ini_file` if you choose to put them in an `.ini` file, you can go further with this and put only the files which contains minimum logic and HTML mostly in the public_html, and from them `include` other files containing logic like controllers, entities, functions etc. which will be outside of public_html.

Comment: I'm still confused on how I would apply this to my scenario. My form in index.html submits to sign_up.php which sends an email. The email function contains the password to an email account, so as per what you said, I can't have this in public_html. How would I use 'include' in this scenario?

Comment: Normally even if you put a password inside a PHP file which is inside the public_html it should be hard to display it you don't `echo` yourself in the code. The hacker must actually find a way to display the actual code written in sign_up.php in order to see the password. I'm not a security expert but it seems to me a hard task to achieve unless getting access to the server I don't know.

Comment: @ShivangPatel You could also see my answer edit to a possible use of `include`.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense now.